# OpenRecordset Method Issue With Too few Parameters

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, dao

This seemingly simple problem has me stopped dead in my tracks for three days now.

My code:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryAutoOrder", dbOpenDynaset)
```

qryAutoOrder is a select query which runs just fine by itself and has no parameters (unless criteria in the query builder count).

When the code runs it hangs on the `set rs =` line and throws this error.

> Run-time error '3061': Too few parameters. Expected 1.

There is more to the code where I would like it to run a loop for each record in the query results so that I can append data to another existing databases tables but it is currently commented out.

Comment: Does the query reference the value of a text box on a form, or any type of control on a form?

Comment: A query that it references does. `completeRFSparts` references `[Forms]![completeRepair]![txtRepairID]`

Comment: But when the script runs, the form is open and I thought that would pass the value along without extra action being taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OpenRecordset` does not resolve the form reference (`[Forms]![completeRepair]![txtRepairID]`) in the query.  In that situation, it is interpreted as a parameter for which you have not supplied a value.

So give it the parameter value via `Eval(prm.Name)` ...

```vb
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.database
Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

'Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryAutoOrder", dbOpenDynaset)
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryAutoOrder")
For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
    prm.value = Eval(prm.Name)
Next
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)
```

You don't actually need a `For` loop there; that's just the way I set these up by habit.  But you could just give it the single parameter value instead ...

```vb
qdf.Parameters(0).Value = [Forms]![completeRepair]![txtRepairID]
```

Comment: I'm not even going to pretend to understand what you did with prm, but it does run without error.

Now to make a do while not rs.EOF work.

Comment: Actually I made a mistake.  Fixed now, but not sure it will be clearer.  `qdf.Parameters` is the collection of parameters the query expects.  `Parameters(0)` is the first of them; in this case the only parameter.  If you use the `For` loop approach, `prm.Name` would give you the parameter "name" --- `[Forms]![completeRepair]![txtRepairID]`  And `Eval(prm.Name)` would give you the value from `[Forms]![completeRepair]![txtRepairID]`

Comment: awesome. I really appreciate the help and the explanation.